# Domain of $y=\ln x$ vs $ y' = 1/x$

Tags: integration, derivatives

If the domain of $y = \ln x$ is $(0, \infty)$, how come the derivative $y'=1/x$ has a domain that is restricted to $(0, \infty)$? Because $y = 1/x$ has the domain $(-\infty, \infty)\backslash{0}$.

Comment: Some special functions such as “lim,” “sin,” “max,” “ln,” and so on are normally set in roman font instead of italic font. Use `\lim`, `\sin`, etc. to make these: `\sin x` $\sin x$, not `sin x` $sin x$. Use subscripts to attach a notation to `\lim`: `\lim_{x\to 0}` $$\lim_{x\to 0}$$

Comment: Btw, the solution of $y'=1/x$ is $y =\ln(\color{red}{|} x \color{red}{|})$ +c.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is restricted to that domain precisely because the original function is. How would you evaluate the derivative of $\ln x$ at negative $x$? You can't, and therefore the derivative is only defined for positive $x$.

The derivative of $\ln x$ does have a very natural extension to the negative numbers. However, that extension has little to do with the original function.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(\ln|x|)'=\frac{1}{x}.$$
Because if $x>0$ we obtain:
$$(\ln|x|)'=(\ln{x})'=\frac{1}{x}$$ and for $x<0$ we obtain:
$$(\ln|x|)'=(\ln(-x))'=-\frac{1}{-x}=\frac{1}{x}.$$